# Install wordpress and replace database (from previous site)

Tags: get-posts

Hi I had a WordPress installed on a shared hosting server. somehow the entire folder gets deleted and hosting provider cant help with this. I only have backup of the theme.

Now I managed to recover database (sql file).
I have just installed a new WordPress site.
Is there any way I can replace the database with my backup.

I only need the posts/categories from previous site. Image I can update later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the server if you are using cpanel restore the database there, on Databases » phpmyadmin » choose the correct database » then to the tab import » choose file (enter your mysql backup) and press go

[image]

[image]

Comment: Finally I managed to restore. I also had to make sure the table prefix matches. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The guide here: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-how-to-restore-wordpress-from-backup/ details how to import a database into a WordPress site. You might want to test it first on a MAMP install or at least back up your current DB before import. Then if things go awry you can roll back your original DB and try again.